# nginx load balancing: wait (but dont timeout) until load falls

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, inference

I have an ML inference server that is able to process about 100 requests per second and if it goes higher it breaks and times out.

Now the actual load sometimes jumps to about 200 requests per second. The clients are fine with waiting for ~2 seconds for the response but are not fine with requests timing out.

I'm thinking of putting up a reverse proxy that can somehow stall the requests when the load is high, but keep them alive and then forward them to the inference server when the load drops. I'm not even sure it's possible and I hope I made my problem clear.

Any advice or suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: You should rather think of scaling your application so that it can handle more requests. If you put incoming requests in a queue then you'll have the same timeouts if a high load period will be 2 or more seconds long.

Comment: @anemyte unfortunately it's not possible at the moment. I'm fine with eventual timeout due to sustained high load, but I need to implement this little "buffer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx has a limit_req option

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html#limit_req

Sets the shared memory zone and the maximum burst size of requests. If the requests rate exceeds the rate configured for a zone, their processing is delayed such that requests are processed at a defined rate. Excessive requests are delayed until their number exceeds the maximum burst size in which case the request is terminated with an error. By default, the maximum burst size is equal to zero. For example, the directives

```
limit_req_zone $server_name zone=one:10m rate=100r/s;

server {
    location /search/ {
        limit_req zone=one burst=500;
    }
```

allow not more than 100 request per second at an average, with bursts not exceeding 500 requests.

The delay parameter (1.15.7) specifies a limit at which excessive requests become delayed. Default value is zero, i.e. all excessive requests are delayed.

There could be several limit_req directives. For example, the following configuration will limit the processing rate of requests coming from a single IP address and, at the same time, the request processing rate by the virtual server:

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=perip:10m rate=1r/s;
limit_req_zone $server_name zone=perserver:10m rate=100r/s;

server {
    ...
    limit_req zone=perip burst=5 nodelay;
    limit_req zone=perserver burst=500;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you